# Intuition for fibers over a point in $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, soft-question

This is a rather soft question, but I would like to see what I get. I'm currently reading/working through Atiyah Macdonald, and I just did exercise 21 of Chapter 3. I won't repeat the entire exercise here as it is rather long, but the point is to get to the identification of $(f^*)^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ with $\operatorname{Spec}(k(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_A B)$, where $f : A \to B$ is a homomorphism of commutative rings, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, and $k(\mathfrak{p})$ is the residue field of $A_\mathfrak{p}$.

My question is: Can someone give geometric intuition about what the fiber over $\mathfrak{p}$ "is", or why we would expect it to be homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}(k(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_A B)$?

I don't know much about schemes, but I have a solid understanding of the basics in classical algebraic geometry (projective varieties, nullstellensatz, etc.), so I would love to get some intuition that makes sense from that perspective.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prime ideal is the "generic point" of an irreducible closed subset $V \subset \operatorname{Spec}A$. Don't worry too much about what this means; the important thing is that the closure of this generic point is the whole set $V$. The fiber over $\mathfrak p$ is close to being the generic point of the inverse image of $V$ under the induced map on spectra (it is called the generic fiber; in the example below it is "uncertain" in the $x$ and $y$ directions but not the $z$ direction), and one might say that the classical intuition is just that you are considering the equations that generate $\mathfrak p$ (an ideal of $A$) as equations in the ring $B$, and then modding out by those equations in $B$.

For instance, the inverse image of the parabola $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y-x^2) = V(y-x^2) \subset \mathbb A^2 = \operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]$ under the projection $\mathbb A^3 \to \mathbb A^2$ corresponding to $k[x,y] \hookrightarrow k[x,y,z]$ is just $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y,z]/(y-x^2) = V(y-x^2) \subset \mathbb A^3$, the "cylinder over the parabola" in $\mathbb A^3$.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the intuition! So where does the extension by the residue field come in? Is there a way to understand why that should be related to the fiber as you've described it?

Comment: @stillconfused set $A = k[x,y]$, $B = A[z]$, and $\mathfrak p = (y - x^2)$. Then $k(\mathfrak p) = k(x,y)/(y-x^2)$, and $k(\mathfrak p)\otimes_A B = k(x,y)[z]/(y-x^2)$. As my edit clarifies, the spectrum of this ring is related to the generic point of the inverse image; it is called the generic fiber, and it is only indefinite in the planar/horizontal direction (but not in the fiber direction).

Comment: @peterag I have made some changes that are hopefully more palatable. The gadget in question is the generic fiber, which in your example is just the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @peterag Extremely!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach for why this is the "right object" goes through the formalism of category theory.

If you recall, the category of Affine Schemes is exactly opposite the category of commutative rings. Depending on your book this is either a definition or a theorem. Next, following our geometric nose, let's see if we can figure out what the [fibre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)) should be in this category.

Well, in the category of topological spaces, we can compute fibres "by [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory))".

[image: a pullback of f along a point]

Here $x$ is the map sending the single point $\star$ to $x \in X$, and the pullback $f^{-1}(x)$ admits the explicit description $\{y \in Y \mid f(y) = x \}$. So we see that this pullback really *is* the fibre of $f$ at $x$, and experience shows that this pullback gives the fibre in all sensible geometric categories.

So then, to build the fibre in the category of affine schemes, we want to imitate this picture. That is, we want to build the inclusion $\{ \mathfrak{p} \} \to \text{Spec}(A)$, and look at the pullback of $f^* : \text{Spec}(B) \to \text{Spec}(A)$ along it.

Of course, we know how to find an affine scheme whose only point is $\mathfrak{p}$! We take $A$, and we *localize* at $\mathfrak{p}$. This gives us a ring $A_\mathfrak{p}$ whose only *maximal* ideal is $\mathfrak{p}$. Then, we quotient in order to make this maximal ideal the *only* ideal, leaving us with $k(\mathfrak{p})$, the residue field of $A_\mathfrak{p}$, whose only ideal is $\mathfrak{p}$ (though this ideal now happens to be equal to $(0)$).

Since we have a map $A \to A_\mathfrak{p} \to k(\mathfrak{p})$, we can apply $\text{Spec}(-)$ to get a map from
$\text{Spec}(k(\mathfrak{p})) \to \text{Spec}(A)$, where $\text{Spec}(k(\mathfrak{p})) = \{ \mathfrak{p} \}$.

Then, by analogy with the topological case, we see the fibre of $f^* : \text{Spec}(B) \to \text{Spec}(A)$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ should be a pullback

[image: a fibre diagram of k(p) into spec(A)]

Now since the category of affine schemes is opposite the category of commutative rings, we know a *pullback* in $\mathsf{Aff}$ is really the same thing as a *pushout* in $\mathsf{CRing}$! But a pushout in $\mathsf{CRing}$ is nothing more than a tensor product!

[image: a pushout of rings]

So if we turn the arrows back around (by applying $\text{Spec}$ to everything in sight) we see that

$$(f^*)^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) \cong \text{Spec}(B \otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p}))$$

as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: This is really good motivation to learn the scheme-theoretic picture better, thanks! I've accepted the other answer because it is more inline with the intent of the question to motivate the fiber from classical algebraic geometry, but both are very helpful.

Comment: Can I also ask, in the last step where you turn all the arrows back around by "applying Spec to everything in sight", in what sense is Spec(Spec(A)) = A? It seems to me more like we are saying that there is some "inverse Spec"-type functor that turns the second diagram naturally into the third, but maybe I am missing something here...

Comment: @stillconfused -- You're right that $\text{Spec}(\text{Spec}(A))$ is meaningless. What I meant is that we apply $\text{Spec}$ to the commutative square of _rings_ which is the last image in my answer. That said, there _is_ an "inverse functor", called $\Gamma$, which takes global sections of the sheaf. $\text{Spec}$ and $\Gamma$ form a pair of contravariant adjoint functors between affine schemes and commutative rings, and in fact give us an equivalence between the two categories.

Comment: Great to know! Hartshorne is in my near future and having this kind of scaffolding for the world of schemes will be really helpful when I dive in more fully